# Connecting to a AWS PostgreSQL database using pgAdmin [Unable to connect to server: connection timed out]

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pgadmin

I have been trying to connect to my RDS postgreSQL database and going through pgAdmin keeps giving me the same error. I have also tried going through psql shell and gotten similar errors. I know that the database instance is running and after each edit, I have tried refreshing the instance.
[Unable to connect to server: connection timed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96ukG.png)
[Unable to connect to server, are you sure the server running on (host) is accepting TCP/IP connections.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdqFf.png)

I've seen multiple questions *on* StackOverflow, but the solutions provided fail to work for me. I'm really not sure what I'm missing or what could be preventing me from successfully connecting.

Attempt 1: Confirming the database is "publicly accessible"
[image that shows the database tagged as publicly accessible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxFSJ.png)

Attempt 2: Providing permissions to my IP address to connect to the database.
I've added to the 'default' security group (as well as trying putting them on the ec2 security group), permission both as 'All Traffic' and as 'PostgreSQL' to allow my IP address. I've attempted this both at my university and at my current place of residence. (I did very shortly put access from ALL IPs just to see if that would work, then removed it)

Attempt 3: I did straight-up delete and remake the database twice.

I've also looked at my pgsql config files and they look correct to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Take a look at the subnet where the database is running -- you will need to confirm whether this is a **public subnet** or a **private subnet**. This can be done by clicking the Subnet that is displayed, which will take you to the VPC management console. Then, navigate to the Route Table associated with that subnet and see whether there is a Route to an Internet Gateway. Let us know what you find! (Or, if you don't understand these instructions, let us know how far you got before being confused.)

Comment: The things to check are: Publicly Accessible, Public Subnet, Security Group permits inbound access on port 5432.